# JS script stops working after more than one id

Tags: javascript, html

I created this javascript function to detect witch option is selected and depending on the selected text it should run an another function. the problem is that it only works with the first "select" id. I have been playing with it for a great amount of time and still I can't figure it out why this happens.

HTML:

```
<div id="amcdiv" class="vanish">
    <label>
        <select id="select" onchange="selection();">
            <option selected>Típus</option>
            <option value="gremlin">Gremlin</option>
        </select>
    </label>
  </div>


<div id="audidiv" class="vanish">
    <label>
        <select id="select" onchange="selection();">
            <option selected>Típus</option>
            <option value="s8">S8</option>
            <option>RS4</option>
            <option>RS7</option>
            <option>R8</option>
        </select>
    </label>
  </div>


<div id="bmwdiv" class="vanish">
    <label>
        <select id="select" onchange="selection();">
            <option selected>Típus</option>
            <option value="e38">750 e38</option>
            <option value="e65">760 e65</option>
            <option value="e46">M3 e46</option>
            <option value="e92">M3 e92</option>
            <option value="m4">M4 2021</option>
            <option value="e34">M5 e34</option>
            <option value="e39">M5 e39</option>
            <option value="e60">M5 e60</option>
            <option value="e24">M635 CSi e24</option>
            <option value="m8">M8 Competition</option>
        </select>
    </label>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function selection() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select").value;
    if (select == "e38") {
      oktext();
    }
    if (select == "e65") {
        oktext();
      }
    if (select == "e46") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "e92") {
      oktext();
    }
    if (select == "e34") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "e39") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "e60") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "m4") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "m4") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "gremlin") {
      goodtext();
    }
    if (select == "s8") {
      goodtext();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Element IDs must be unique by definition . Think of them like an address in the document

Comment: `select` is a reserved keyword in javascript

Comment: Pass a reference, like `<select  onchange="selection(this);">` then `function selection(el) {
    var sel = el.value; ...` - as mentioned try not to use reserved keywords like 'select' as variables

Comment: `select` is not at all a reserved word in JS. Your problem is duplicate IDs, as already observed by @charlietfl.

Comment: So if I change the getElementById to getElementsByClassName and the ids to classes it should work?

Comment: It's not working like that.

Comment: Not quite because getElementsByClassName () returns a collection not a single element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is what you're looking to achieve:

HTML:

```
<div id="amcdiv" class="vanish">
  <label>
    <select onchange="selection(this.value);">
      <option value="Tipus" selected>Típus</option>
      <option value="gremlin">Gremlin</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="audidiv" class="vanish">
  <label>
    <select onchange="selection(this.value);">
      <option value="Tipus" selected>Típus</option>
      <option value="s8">S8</option>
      <option value="RS4">RS4</option>
      <option value="RS7">RS7</option>
      <option value="R8">R8</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="bmwdiv" class="vanish">
  <label>
    <select onchange="selection(this.value);">
      <option value="Tipus" selected>Típus</option>
      <option value="e38">750 e38</option>
      <option value="e65">760 e65</option>
      <option value="e46">M3 e46</option>
      <option value="e92">M3 e92</option>
      <option value="m4">M4 2021</option>
      <option value="e34">M5 e34</option>
      <option value="e39">M5 e39</option>
      <option value="e60">M5 e60</option>
      <option value="e24">M635 CSi e24</option>
      <option value="m8">M8 Competition</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

JS

```
function selection(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

You can now react to any string generated by any selection input. Remember to always have `value` field in each `option` node.

When it comes to why your code was not working, it was getting lost on `id=select` that was not unique and would always return the currently selected value of the first (found in the DOM) node with `id=select`. Another thing was that it also could not understand `option` nodes that did not have `value` attribute set.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript ids must be unique and different. If you want one single id, use class instead.

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp <= html id
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp <= html classes

Comment: Oh sorry I think I mixed something up!